# How to export an error when entering the value in Qty column in the table Sales greater value in the column in the table QOH Item_Detail (Use trigger)

Tags: triggers

I HAVE TWO TABLES: Sales and Item_Details

### Sales

```
Sl_No,
Item_No,  
Price,  
Qty,
Date_of_sale
```

### Item_Details

```
Item_No,    
Item_Name,    
Price, 
QOH
```

I have two questions : 1/How to export an error when entering the value in Qty column in the table Sales greater value in the column in the table QOH Item_Detail (Use trigger)

```
                    2/Create an index Fulltext index on Sales table and use freetext for comments from the 'Lux' in the 'Item Name'
```

Please, help me! Thanks everyone very much!

Answer (score 0):

*I would no try to enforce this rule as a DB layer rule.*

Given the fact that **Sales** might contain multiple entries for a given *item_details*, and the item_details seems to be containg the entries for a selected item being sold, *this seems like an applicationlogic issue*.

*Dont try fixing the application at the DB level if it is not required.*